# how to share reports with PowerBi premium P1 with report Server, without Pro PBI

Tags: powerbi, report, powerbi-desktop

**My company has bought a PowerBi premium P1  with report Server, but still we are  not able to  open shared reports without Pro.**
I have tried using Power bi App to open the shared reports but is asking to get the pro licences. We all are on same mail domain, using same SQl data base(2014) and all have access to SQl data. Please suggest a solution for it.

Comment: Is the premium capacity assigned to the workspace, where these reports are published?

Comment: No, Couldn't find how to do that.  Can please help with steps to do this?. When I tried to add users to Premium license as a admin, its not allowing me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to assign the workspace, where the reports are published, to a dedicated capacity (i.e. the Power BI Premium, that you paid for) to be able to share the workspace with non-Pro (i.e. Power BI Free) users. To do this, [edit the workspace](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/service-manage-app-workspace-in-power-bi-and-office-365) by clicking the three dots next to its name and select `Edit this workspace`:

[image]

And then at the bottom of the pane, expand `Advanced` section, flip `Dedicated capacity` switch to `On` and select a capacity from the list:

[image]

See more at [Assigning workspaces to capacities](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/service-premium-capacity-manage#assigning-workspaces-to-capacities).

When the workspace is assigned to a dedicated capacity, only publishers needs Power BI Pro licenses, while consumers can see reports even if they have only Power BI Free license.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I am able to publish reports now.